# Constrained optimisation via substitution

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Trying to minimize xy+49xz+7yz subject to xyz=1, via substitution.
Can not get the objective function to reduce to two variables. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This question looks perfect for lagrange multipliers, are you sure you're not allowed to use that?

Comment: No, question requires use of the substitution method.

Answer (score 0):

$$z= \frac{1}{xy}$$

Hence you problem reduces to 
 minimizing
$$xy+\frac{49}{y}+\frac{7}{x}$$

which is an unconstrained problem in two variables now.

Comment: Yes, that is what I thought and then was able to work it through. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: with the substitutions $\,x = \cfrac{u}{\sqrt{7}}\,$, $\,y = \sqrt{7} \,v\,$, $\,z = \cfrac{w}{7 \sqrt{7}}$ the problem reduces to minimizing $u\,v + u\,w+ v\,w$ subject to $u\,v\,w = 7 \sqrt{7}$.

If $x,y,z$ are known to be non-negative by any chance, this can be solved with AM-GM directly.